# How do I parachute down high places in Bad Company 2?

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

I sometimes see people comfortably parachuting down high places like buildings or hilltops. How do I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you jump off of a ledge, immediately press spacebar again and it will deploy your parachute.